# What is this status bar icon?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, verizon, motorola

[image: screenshot]

Verizon Moto X - Stock - 4.4.4
Only pops up every once in a while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my phone (Moto G running 4.4.4) this symbol appears when the phone is set to use "High Accuracy Mode" (i.e. use the GPS rather than Wi-Fi/phone network for location) and some app requests the location.

Comment: thanks for this answer! I couldn't figure out how to describe this icon to google...once you started talking about location, I found [http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-mobile-lg-g2/382738-upside-down-tear-drop-icon-status-bar-t-mobile-lg-g2.html] which seems to confirm.

Comment: as a side note: any idea why the stock messaging app would request location?